# Install GNU-Classpath without Jack/Gnome/Xinerama and other "bloat"

Tags: memory, java, yum, gtk, openvz

I need (desperately) to install GNU-Classpath on a console-only VPS to run a small java server. Due to incompatibilities with OpenVZ, I can't get the normal java VM to run. I have the normal VM installed, but I also have JamVM which will work, but needs a classpath. This issue comes down to the fact that GNU-Classpath requires several libraries that I will never user, and do not want to install, including the GTK libraries (no use in console). Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Additionaly, I have no idea if I should put this here or at serverfault, the category which this question falls in seems rather vague to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running some fedora or red hat derivative, (which i guess from the tags), you could probably use the ----nodeps option with yum. You may have to install some essential packages as needed by hand, since this will totally turn off dependancy tracking for that install.

Comment: Will try, I'll get back about whether it works or not